# can a life exist outside the universe?

Tags: galaxy, exoplanet, cosmology, life

can a life exist outside of universe. but we know that in our universe many galaxies have life  without water and oxygen and it is possible that life exist outside the universe so help me to find the right answer??and what is the possibility of this??

Comment: "we know that in our universe many galaxies have life without water and oxygen" - do you have an authorative source that states this?  I do not think this question is answerable.

Comment: but life can exist outside the universe

Comment: what evidence is there for this claim? Preferably backed up by an authoritive source

Comment: we all know that life can exist without water and oxygen the main point is outside the universe

Comment: There is no way to answer this, especially as we do not definitively have any idea what is 'outside' the Universe.

Comment: in word outside i also "trouble" please help me to find answer

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this appears to be about metaphysics - as it asks a question about what happens outside the Universe

Comment: Brane cosmology? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brane_cosmology Scientists know very little about life beyond earth. A few simple amino acids and nucleotide precursors have shown up in meteorites, but we've yet to even get a chlorophyll spectrum off any exoplanet. Life beyond our galaxy, far less our universe, is a total unknown.

Comment: @alexhits Welcome to Astronomy Stack Exchange! Please note that in science we rarely discuss things without definition. In order to talk about an "outside" of the Universe, you would have to first define what the "outside" is and how we might falsify this theory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> can a life exist outside of universe.

There's no way to define "outside of universe" I know of.

> we all know that life can not exist without water and oxygen

We don't know that.  It's an assumption, and not one I would make.  I would not even make it about Earth.

> but we know that in our universe many galaxies have life without water and oxygen

We certainly do not know that.  It contradicts your original statement, but there's been no evidence found of life anywhere except on Earth ( to date ).  There are many theories saying life probably exists ( in some basic form, like cells ) outside of Earth, but they are simply theories at this point.  Science is not about excepting theories without evidence, it's about theories fitting evidence.  At this point we have no theories on life outside Earth that we have evidence to back.

> and it is possible that life exist outside the universe

Again, we cannot define "outside the universe" so that has no real meaning.

> so help me to find the right answer??

Perhaps try the PBS Space Time channel on YouTube, as it discusses these things at a reachable level.  It recently discussed life ( advanced technological civilizations ) and why we cannot see any evidence of them in several videos.  Worth a look and they also make great introductions to advanced current thinking in space-time physics, including ideas like the multiverse, which often mislead people.  They usually supply links for people who want to get more serious about study as well as the video overview.

Comment: your answer is not clarifying my question

Comment: @alexhits Actually, this is a very good answer to the question as you wrote it. It addresses every aspect of the question you wrote, which shows lack of research and clarification of your point.